# MS Access - column choice based on the other column

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a simple database which will allow users to manage cars and contains data like registration number, brand, model, dates of upcoming maintenance controls... (in my country marka = brand)

I have created relations like this:

[image]

In `t_podwozie` I have created link & relation columns `fk_marka`, `fk_model`. I need `fk_model` choices to be limited by my choice in `fk_marka`.

[image]

I have tried to use a query connecting brands and model (INNER JOIN) but then I can save only one column in `t_podwozie`. Any advice?

Both link & relation columns consist of `id` column and name column (id's are hidden)

Comment: I think you need cascading (dependent) combobox, a common topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access form cascading combo box shows nothing in drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969226/access-form-cascading-combo-box-shows-nothing-in-drop-down-menu)

Comment: Note that the dupe is right, but it only works on forms. On tables, queries and continuous forms, this unfortunately is not possible.