# I need to return the results of a query to a combo box in a form using an SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I'm making a research database & have about 20 (topical) Categories plus over 600 Subcategories. Selecting the category (as I type an entry) should narrow the options I can pick to the appropriate records from tblSubcategory. I made a tblSummary_Details where all the IDs connect my category entries with the entries of research themselves. I made a form called frmSubcategory with a CategoryId listbox & a cboCat-Subcat combo control. Using the lookup wizard, I can see all the Subcategory Ids in there, all the CategoryIds, & the names of the
Subcategories.

I also made a qryCat-Subcategory with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    tblSubcategory.SubcategoryId, tblSubcategory.CategoryId AS Expr1, 
    tblSubcategory.Subcategory
FROM 
    tblSubcategory 
INNER JOIN 
    tblCategory ON tblSubcategory.CategoryId = tblCategory.CategoryID
WHERE 
    (([frmSubcategory<CategoryId>]) = [frm.Expr1:CategoryId]"))
```

I feel my ability to follow instructions breaks down more as I get to the end of this SQL statement & I really don't know what I'm doing any more. I NEED help & really appreciate anything you'll do. I want to return to the combo box in the form a result that would narrow the Id options & names of the subcategories to pick from, based on whichever category ID I input into this form, as I input records of research.

Comment: Are you asking for help with the SQL statement itself or with filtering the subcategory drop down box based on the category that was selected?

Comment: What you describe is known as cascading combobox - a very common topic in many forums. Why use Expr1 alias field name? What is form name? `= frm!formname.CategoryId))`. Need to Requery subcategory combobox after selection of category.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access form cascading combo box shows nothing in drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969226/access-form-cascading-combo-box-shows-nothing-in-drop-down-menu)